# get ID of li when swiped

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I have a list as follows.

```
<ul id="hook_list">
<li id="a1">one</li>
<li id="a2">two</li>
<li id="a3">three</li>
<li id="a4">four</li>
</ul>
```

I am using `hammer.js` to detect swipe events ..

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('hook_list');
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
mc.on("swipe", function(ev) {
    alert('Detect swipe');
});
```

It detects the swipe no problem but I am not sure how to pull the `id` from the swiped `li`. I have tried `$(this).attr('id')` as I have jquery on the same page but I just get `undefined`.

How do I get the `id` from the swiped `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are binding the swipe event to the `ul`, you can't use `this` to get the id of the `ul`

However, since you have the reference to the `event` object in `ev` you can use the `ev` and use `ev.target.id`

Comment: for some reason `$(this).attr('id')` does not work but `ev.target.id` does. Thanks very much

Comment: `this` won't work because you're binding the `swipe` event to the `ul`, not the `li`